# Cannot get type by full name despite this type exists and is loaded

Tags: c#, reflection, mono, unity-game-engine

Weird problem, I get System.TypeLoadException "Could not load type 'Color'":

```
using UnityEngine;

Type.GetType(typeof(Color).FullName, true);
```

Of course, I cannot just use `typeof(Color)`, the code demonstrates that this type exists and is loaded and its name is correct.

`typeof(Color).FullName` == "UnityEngine.Color".

I also tried:

```
typeof(Color).Module.GetTypes().First(t => t.Name == "Color")
```

works fine, but

```
typeof(Color).Module.GetType("Color", true, false)
```

throws `TypeLoadException`. So I make a conclusion that it's not a "fully qualified name" problem but something else.

I also tried another types from `UnityEngine` assembly and from another 3rd-party assembly.

I checked Mono sources but related code is in C implementation and is quite difficult to comprehend quickly.

Comment: Can you declare a variable of type `Color`, ie. drop the reflection, can you still use the type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Type.FullName` doesn't include the assembly - so unless the type is in either the calling assembly or `mscorlib`, it won't be found.

Basically, if you're trying to load a type from an arbitrary assembly there are two simple options:

- Use the assembly-qualified name within `Type.GetType()`
- Use `Assembly.GetType`

If you know another type in the same assembly at compile-time, it's often simplest to use:

```
Type type = typeof(KnownType).Assembly.GetType("Qualified.UnknownType");
```

Comment: Hm, by-assembly way works and I'm surprised. Why it's different to what I tried with `Module.GetType`?

Comment: @AndyT: Well you're not passing in the namespace-qualified name - try with `typeof(Color).Module.GetType(typeof(Color).FullName, true, false)` and it should work.

Comment: I'm still a bit surprised why I should pass fully qualified name to *module* type resolution, it's already kind of a local namespace, isn't it?

Comment: @AndyT: No, namespaces are entirely orthogonal to both modules and assemblies. You can have a module which includes types in multiple namespaces.